# loop does not continue after a 'space' is entered after a string input in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, strtok

I have tried many methods but im still not sure why my loop does not continue after the user enters a space at the end of the input. Ideal im trying to take the sentences and store them in a singly linked list where each node will contain each line the user enters.

```
void addSentence(control* list)
{
sentence* sList;
sentence* currentSentence;
word* words;


printf("Enter a Sentence:");
char sentenceInput[1000];

while(fgets(sentenceInput, 1000, stdin) != NULL && sentenceInput[0] != '\n')
{
   
    words = (word*)malloc(sizeof(word));
    words->pWord = sentenceInput;
    sList = createSentence(words);
    words->pWord = strtok(sentenceInput, " ");

    while(words->pWord != NULL)
    {
        if(list->firstSentence == NULL)
        {
            list->firstSentence = sList;
        }
        else
        {
            for(currentSentence = list->firstSentence; currentSentence->nextSentence != NULL; currentSentence = currentSentence->nextSentence);
            currentSentence->nextSentence = sList;
        }
        printf("%s ", words->pWord);
        words->pWord = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }


    printf("Enter a Sentence:");
}
```

}

and here is the structure

```
    typedef struct{
    char* pWord;
    int numOfChar;
    int posOfWord;
    struct word* nextWord;}word;


typedef struct{
    word* wordList;
    int posOfLine;
    int totalWords;
    struct sentence* nextSentence;}sentence;

typedef struct{
    int sentenceCounter;
    struct sentence* firstSentence;}control;
```

Comment: Why should it continue if it's the "end of the input"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: I want it so it will continue asking for input until a blank line is entered. Right now it asks for the input for about 2 lines before it stops and does not continue in the loop.

Comment: Please show the exact log of your test run. When you say "does not continue", what happens? Also please give complete minimal code as already requested. That is, code that anyone can copy exactly as shown to run and reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is separate from the question you asked, but you need to be careful with the `sentenceInput`.  You assign some `strtok`-modified portions of `sentenceInput` to `pWord`, but then the next time through the loop you fill `sentenceInput` with a new call to `fgets`, meaning the `words` struct you malloced last time through the loop is now pointing to some completely new content.  In other words, you create a new `words` struct every time through but they all end up pointing to the same `sentenceInput` buffer.  You should probably be making copies with `strdup` before assigning.